# Phonegap Build Error: no iPhone Developer/Distribution identity found on your certificate

Tags: ios, build-process, cordova, signing

Does anybody have experience build app with PhoneGap's Build Service?

I followed the steps and created a `.p12` file and the `provisioning profile` file. When I uploaded the keys, it does not build my iOS App giving the following error/warning:

`no iPhone Developer/Distribution identity found on your certificate`

The steps I followed are:

> 1) Using Keychain Access:    Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant
>   -> Request Certificate from a Certificate Authority
>
> 2) Provided the email address which I used to register on Apple
>   Developer Program
>
> 3) I am not sure if the 'Common Name' matters, but I used a custom
>   name
>
> 4) 2048 bits RSA key pair value
>
> 5) From the iOS Development Portal, followed the wizard "Launch
>   Assistant, to generate the provisioning profile.
>
> 6) Downloaded the developer certificate and provisioning profile
>
> 7) Exported the private key created above by giving a password to
>   generate the .p12 file
>
> 8) Used the .p12 file & provisioning profile created in last two steps
>   in the 'signing' section of PhoneGap's build service.

Has anybody faced a similar problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/no_iphone_developer_distribution_identity_found_on_your_certificate

Comment: @PhilipK: can you post the steps you followed. I think I have this solved now, and can help you if you post YOUR actual steps...

Comment: Pretty sure I followed the steps you had mentioned. Please post your solution any answer would be better then the current answer.

Comment: If you followed the steps as mentioned in the question then I believe you would be having keys & certificates former than one developer account, and would have thus messed it. See my answer below, and let me know if that helps!

Comment: My Question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531812/no-iphone-developer-distribution-identity-found-on-your-certificate-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience I have found that this is actually caused when you inter mix the public/private keys, certificates and provisioning profiles from multiple developer accounts.

So, to eliminate the problem I deleted the public & private key for the account which I wanted to use in PhoneGap build and even deleted the certificate; then followed the steps mentioned in my question and it worked like charm.

In short, give it a scratch start and generate the files again...

Comment: Hey hie mahendra I am having same problem what you had before. Can you please tell me steps what you followed. I followed http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Does this not mean you have to submit the app as a brand new app, ie not an update for the current app?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the certificate was associated with the wrong private key.

One should set up a test app to sign in Xcode first and then export the certificate form there.

I will post detailed steps shortly...