# No iPhone Developer/Distribution identity found on your certificate Error

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-build

I made the IOS application using PhoneGap Build its working fine, but now I wanted to add (APNS) notification for that I made iPhone Developer Certificate from Mac for push notification and p12 file, provisioning profile.
I followed all the steps mentioned [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).

Still it shows No iPhone Developer/Distribution identity found on your certificate Error while building my application.

Is this the right way what I am doing or any other solutions to do it let mi know.

[image: PhoneGap build error]

Comment: I found that if you don't select both the key and the certificate while exporting then both are not included.

Comment: Even i tried this also. I selected both key and certificate and export 2 items stil no sucess.

Comment: Can anyone face this type of problem before..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally I got my solution after a long time.

Just follow [these](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) steps.

And while you are building your application through Phonegap Build use Provisioning profile which you made using above steps.

`.P12` - Use .p12 file of your any development or production certificate depend on situation if you are doing for development then use any development certificate associated .p12 file and if you are doing for production then use any production certificate associated .p12 file.

If you are using .p12 file of certificate you have made it using these steps then you will get above error while building the app.

Answer (score 3):

Just spent an hour on this - evan is correct. most likely you exported only your private key and did not select both the certificate and the private key for export. both of them result in a .p12 file.

Comment: This belongs in a comment. Please +1 someone else's comment until you are able to comment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Keychain Access --> My Certificates
2. Select the
   Certificate you plan to use and cross-check by expanding it (Select
   the drop-down icon on the left) to verify the private key.
3. Right
   click and export it.
4. Make sure that the provisioning profile you
   plan to use is signed with the certificate which you are exporting

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanx mahendra for Reply. As what you are suggesting i have done that before still stuck with same issue. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1  ... steps which are given in this blog which I followed. Is that right?

Comment: Hey Mahendara Let me know if steps which I am following are wrong.

Comment: I can just say that the combination of your certificate and provisioning profile is incorrect. If you are still not able to solve it, I would strongly suggest you give this a fresh start from scratch i.e. generate everything again (shouldn't take more than 30-40 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - the solution was as Mahendra says, that you must select BOTH the certificate and the private key, i.e. using cmd and clicking them both, when exporting from Keychain (and then make sure that you select the same certificate in the provisioning profile of course).